# Display user picture in User Relationship block

Tags: 7, views, users

In my social networking site, i have provided for users to be able to forge relationships between themselves using the User relationship module. This is working fine. I am creating a tab using quicktab to display the user their relations when he or she clicks on them. I assign my tab the block value :
My Relationships: All relationships (user_relationship_blocks:my-all)
which is already available in DRUPAL. However it does not show the picture of the user with whom the relationship is. I thought of using views but in views all relationship are showed. What i need is something like this:

**Followers**

User A (A's Picture)   User B (B's Picture)

**Following**

User C (C's Picture)   User D (D's Picture)

If this can be done using views or any other way, please advice...thanks

Edit/Update:

I tried using the default block provided:
**My Relationships: All relationships (user_relationships_blocks:my-all)**
This is under structure/blocks...I just enable it and display it...Its showing:

[image] 
Now i just need that the user picture also appears besides their name...Please advice/help...DO i have to do some changes in this block, if so, then just get me on starting line, i will carry it forward :)
Thanks

Comment: I tried using views but am unable to get the result i want...would appreciate any help

Comment: this seems to be a simple thing to do but i am not getting it...would appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

$view = new view();
$view->name = 'user_freinds';
$view->description = 'Shows someone\'s related users';
$view->tag = '';
$view->base_table = 'user_relationships';
$view->human_name = 'User freinds';
$view->core = 0;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Defaults */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Defaults', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'mini';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['items_per_page'] = '10';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['offset'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['options']['id'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'grid';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['grouping'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['columns'] = '5';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
$handler->display->display_options['row_options']['inline'] = array(
  'name_1' => 'name_1',
);
$handler->display->display_options['row_options']['separator'] = ', ';
/* No results behavior: Global: Text area */
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['id'] = 'area';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['table'] = 'views';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['field'] = 'area';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['empty'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['content'] = 'لا يوجد محتوى';
$handler->display->display_options['empty']['area']['format'] = 'plain_text';
/* Relationship: User relationships: Requestee user */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['requestee_id']['id'] = 'requestee_id';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['requestee_id']['table'] = 'user_relationships';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['requestee_id']['field'] = 'requestee_id';
/* Relationship: User relationships: Requester user */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['requester_id']['id'] = 'requester_id';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['requester_id']['table'] = 'user_relationships';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['requester_id']['field'] = 'requester_id';
/* Relationship: User relationships: RTID */
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['rtid']['id'] = 'rtid';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['rtid']['table'] = 'user_relationships';
$handler->display->display_options['relationships']['rtid']['field'] = 'rtid';
/* Field: User relationship types: Plural name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['plural_name']['id'] = 'plural_name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['plural_name']['table'] = 'user_relationship_types';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['plural_name']['field'] = 'plural_name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['plural_name']['relationship'] = 'rtid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['plural_name']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['plural_name']['exclude'] = TRUE;
/* Field: User: Picture */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['picture']['id'] = 'picture';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['picture']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['picture']['field'] = 'picture';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['picture']['relationship'] = 'requestee_id';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['picture']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['picture']['element_label_colon'] = FALSE;
/* Field: User: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['relationship'] = 'requestee_id';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['label'] = '';
/* Sort criterion: User relationship types: Plural name */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['plural_name']['id'] = 'plural_name';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['plural_name']['table'] = 'user_relationship_types';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['plural_name']['field'] = 'plural_name';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['plural_name']['relationship'] = 'rtid';
/* Contextual filter: User relationships: Requester user */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['requester_id']['id'] = 'requester_id';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['requester_id']['table'] = 'user_relationships';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['requester_id']['field'] = 'requester_id';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['requester_id']['default_action'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['requester_id']['exception']['title_enable'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['requester_id']['default_argument_type'] = 'user';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['requester_id']['default_argument_options']['user'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['requester_id']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['requester_id']['specify_validation'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['requester_id']['validate']['type'] = 'numeric';
$handler->display->display_options['filter_groups']['groups'] = array(
  1 => 'AND',
  2 => 'AND',
);
/* Filter criterion: User relationships: Relationship status */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['approved']['id'] = 'approved';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['approved']['table'] = 'user_relationships';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['approved']['field'] = 'approved';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['approved']['value'] = '1';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['approved']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['approved']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;

/* Display: Block by type */
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Block by type', 'block_1');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['use_ajax'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['use_ajax'] = TRUE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['hide_admin_links'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['block_description'] = 'Display user\'s relationships grouped by relationship type';

/* Display: Block by user */
$handler = $view->new_display('block', 'Block by user', 'block_2');
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['title'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'Related users';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['hide_admin_links'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'list';
$handler->display->display_options['style_options']['grouping'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['style_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_plugin'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['row_options'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['defaults']['fields'] = FALSE;
/* Field: User relationship types: Plural name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['plural_name']['id'] = 'plural_name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['plural_name']['table'] = 'user_relationship_types';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['plural_name']['field'] = 'plural_name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['plural_name']['relationship'] = 'rtid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['plural_name']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['plural_name']['exclude'] = TRUE;
/* Field: User: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['id'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['table'] = 'users';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['relationship'] = 'requestee_id';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name']['exclude'] = TRUE;
/* Field: Broken/missing handler */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['updated_at']['id'] = 'updated_at';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['updated_at']['table'] = 'user_relationships';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['updated_at']['field'] = 'updated_at';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['updated_at']['label'] = 'Added';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['updated_at']['exclude'] = TRUE;
/* Field: User relationship types: Name */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name_1']['id'] = 'name_1';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name_1']['table'] = 'user_relationship_types';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name_1']['field'] = 'name';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name_1']['relationship'] = 'rtid';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['name_1']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['block_description'] = 'Display user\'s relationships grouped by user';

Comment: here is the export for the view

Answer (score 0):

Download and enable the module UR-Views

then you will see a view called user-friends with two blocks

1-block by type 
2-block by user

select the first and so you could make  your own content-panes or blocks for further needs

Comment: UR-Views comes along with the User Relationship module in Drupal7. I have already installed that but i do not see any views such as user-friends

Comment: I have the module with drupal 7 and enabled 5 modules 1-UR-blocks 2-UR-Private message integration 3-UR-UI 4-User Relationships 5-UR-Views and found the default blocks and that view so try clear cache and read the docs

Comment: @Mhmdgomma...have done that already

Comment: you really need to be more specific and responsive...this is no way to help

Comment: sorry friend i was so busy and forget to respond